# Add(GObject obj) method doesn't draw the object on the applet

Tags: java, methods, graphics, applet, acm-java-libraries

This is my code, it''s just a small part of a program for a Tic Tac Toe game. This part is supposed to draw the board on the applet, but everytime, nothing appears.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TTTb extends GraphicsProgram {

    private double Height = getHeight();
    private double Width = getWidth();
    private static int col_num = 3;
    private static int row_num = 3;

    public void run() {
        GLine Border1 = new GLine(0, Height/3, Width, Height/3);
        GLine Border2 = new GLine(0, Height*2/3, Width, Height*2/3);
        GLine Border3 = new GLine(Width/3, 0, Width/3, Height);
        GLine Border4 = new GLine(Width*2/3, 0, Width*2/3, Height);
        add(Border1);
        add(Border2);
        add(Border3);
        add(Border4);
    }
}
```

I've also tried other Gobjects, but there was no success.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`run()`](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html#run%28%29):

> Specifies the code to be executed as the program runs. The `run` method is required for applications *that have a thread of control that runs even in the absence of user actions*, such as a program that uses console interation or that involves animation. GUI-based programs that operate by setting up an initial configuration and then wait for user events usually do not specify a `run` method and supply a new definition for `init` instead.

I read that to mean that it will only be called if the app. creates a `Thread` based on the `GraphicsProgram` (a `Runnable`) and explicitly calls `Thread.start()`.

Change it to `init()` and it should work. The `init` method is explicitly called by the Java Virtual Machine that loads an applet.

Comment: I actually gave that a try before posting the question, but there were no changes

Comment: Well, nice of you to show that in your code sample..  Oh wait, you *didn't.*  Don't expect your audience to be psychic!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of pointless code tweaking, i found out that by defining the height and width variables inside the run method, the board was showing up just fine.